# How to execute a menu.vim function from within vimrc?

Tags: function, vim, menu

I know that it is possible to call a vimrc function from menu.vim
but is it also possible the other way around?

p.e. Writing this in vimrc does't work:

```
nmap <F4> :call <SID>MyFunction_in_menuvim()<CR>
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: What kind of error do you get ?

Comment: @Paco, `Unknown function: <SNR>1_MyFunction_in_menuvim` (same for whatever function in menu.vim)

Comment: Is it a global function or a local function? If you made that function global, if won't need <SID>

Comment: I'll add an answer. This might be useful for other users ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<SID>` is used for local functions. If your function is not local, you do not need to add this. `<SID>` will be replace by a string like: `<SNR>23_`

See [vim documentation on map](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3CSID%3E) for more information

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and tried but didn't think of the <SID> prefix.